# Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment

Tags: javascript

I have the following function in my javascript code:

```
  addParam(url, param, value) {
    var a = document.createElement('a'), regex = /(?:\?|&amp;|&)+([^=]+)(?:=([^&]*))*/g;
    var match, str = []; a.href = url; param = encodeURIComponent(param);

    while(match = regex.exec(a.search)) {
      if(param != match[1]) {
        str.push(match[1] + (match[2] ? '=' + match[2] : ''));
      }
    }

    str.push(param + (value ? '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) : ''));
    a.search = str.join('&');
    return a.href;
  }
```

eslint returns me following error:

```
  306:15  error  Expected a conditional expression and instead saw an assignment  no-cond-assign
```

The problem is this while statement:

```
while(match = regex.exec(a.search)) {
  if(param != match[1]) {
    str.push(match[1] + (match[2] ? '=' + match[2] : ''));
  }
}
```

How can I rewrite this to fix that?

Comment: This is an old trick: `while((match = regex.exec(a.search)))`. But it’s cleaner to just split this up into multiple statements.

Comment: What is input and expected result?

Comment: If you like my answer, please consider giving it the green check of approval, thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You want to do:

```
while((match = regex.exec(a.search))) {
  if(param != match[1]) {
    str.push(match[1] + (match[2] ? '=' + match[2] : ''));
  }
}
```

you need that extra set of parentheses

Comment: But why do we need them?

Comment: Syntactically necessary...o/w there is ambiguity so the compiler doesnt know which path to choosw